# ADD statement WHEN CASE SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this: 
[image]

and this is my query for showing avaibility of room

```
SELECT 
hotel.nama_hotel,
hotel.kota,
room.id_room,
room.position,
room.price,
room_price.date_start,
room_price.date_end,
room_price.price
FROM room
    JOIN hotel on room.id_hotel = hotel.id_hotel
    JOIN room_price on room.id_room = room_price.id_room
    WHERE 
        (
            room.id_room NOT IN 
            (
            SELECT id_room FROM booking 
                WHERE 
                (
                    booking_start BETWEEN '2018-02-10' AND '2018-02-11' OR 
                    booking_end   BETWEEN '2018-02-10' AND '2018-02-11' OR 
                    '2018-02-10'  BETWEEN booking_start AND booking_end OR
                    '2018-02-11'  BETWEEN booking_start AND booking_end
                ) 
            )
        )
    AND (room.status = 1) 
    AND (hotel.kota="Bandung")
    AND (room.position = "earth")
```

and i got 2 column of price from table `room` and table `room_price`

i need 1 column of price when inserted date is between `room_price.date_start` AND `room_price.date_end` and price appear from table `room_price` 
when is not on between `room_price.date_start` AND `room_price.date_end` the price appear from table `room`

is that possible to do that ?

**EDIT**

this the query

```
SELECT 
hotel.nama_hotel,
hotel.kota,
room.id_room,
room.position,
room_price.date_start,
room_price.date_end,
    (
        CASE WHEN 
        (
            '2018-02-10' BETWEEN room_price.date_start AND room_price.date_end
        )THEN  
        room.price = room_price.price
        ELSE room.price = room.price END
    ) as price from room 



   JOIN hotel on room.id_hotel = hotel.id_hotel
    JOIN room_price on room.id_room = room_price.id_room
    WHERE 
        (
            room.id_room NOT IN 
            (
            SELECT id_room FROM booking 
                WHERE 
                (
                    booking_start BETWEEN '2018-02-10' AND '2018-02-11' OR 
                    booking_end   BETWEEN '2018-02-10' AND '2018-02-11' OR 
                    '2018-02-10'  BETWEEN booking_start AND booking_end OR
                    '2018-02-11'  BETWEEN booking_start AND booking_end
                ) 
            )
        )
    AND (room.status = 1) 
    AND (hotel.kota="Bandung")
    AND (room.position = "earth")
```

BUT i dont get the `price` = `room_price.price`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE IF() in your SELECT this would save your time.

```
hotel.nama_hotel,
hotel.kota,
room.id_room,
room.position,
room_price.date_start,
room_price.date_end,
IF('2018-02-10' BETWEEN room_price.date_start AND room_price.date_end, room_price.price, room.price)
FROM room
INNER JOIN hotel ON room.id_hotel = hotel.id_hotel
INNER JOIN room_price ON room.id_room = room_price.id_room
WHERE 
    room.id_room NOT IN( 
    SELECT id_room 
    FROM booking 
    WHERE 
        booking_start BETWEEN '2018-02-10' AND '2018-02-11' OR 
        booking_end   BETWEEN '2018-02-10' AND '2018-02-11' OR 
        '2018-02-10'  BETWEEN booking_start AND booking_end OR
        '2018-02-11'  BETWEEN booking_start AND booking_end

                    )
AND (room.status = 1) 
AND (hotel.kota="Bandung")
AND (room.position = "earth")
```

I'm not sure if you need room.id_room NOT IN (...) with it or not, as

```
IF('2018-02-10' BETWEEN room_price.date_start AND room_price.date_end, room_price.price, room.price)
```

Will check the date, if is it true, then will return the price from room_price.price, if is it false, then it will return room.price.

more about it

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

you miss a `,` after the 9th line after `room.price`, when you open a bracket `(`, SQL think you are calling a function `room.price()`

Comment: thats fix the error but i dont get the state as price from `price_room`